# Customizar pantalla de impresión

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar una pantalla de impresión customizada, pero no hay manera de que me recoja los valores que quiero que tenga para la previsualización.

```
<div id="elementToPrint">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<svg id="barcode"></svg>
```

```
JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi world!");
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
ifr.style = 'size: auto; size: A5; margin: 25mm;'
document.body.appendChild(ifr);

$('#elementToPrint').clone().appendTo(ifr.contentDocument.body);
ifr.contentWindow.print();

ifr.parentElement.removeChild(ifr);
```

- Fiddle con ejemplo funcional ya que el del sitio no funciona correctamente con la impresión:
  https://jsfiddle.net/Lytqsd2x/

El resultado de esto es una pantalla genérica del navegador y sin márgenes ni de tamaño A5, también he tratado de usar `@media` pero sin éxito:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: auto;
        size: A5;
        margin: 25mm;
    }
}
```

> ¿Cómo puedo configurar esta pantalla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo bien el motivo pero según he visto, la única manera de poder customizar el tamaño de papel de impresión es desde la configuración de la impresora, desde Javascript no puedes designar tamaños, no se si se trata de una medida de seguridad, ya que en varios sitios vi que desde css si se podía hacer, pero al tratar de reproducir esos casos ninguno salió satisfactoriamente, **no puedes generar una pantalla de impresión custom**. Pero puedes realizarlo desde el sistema de windows accediendo a:

1. Windows
2. Configuración
3. Dispositivos
4. Impresoras
5. Seleccionar impresora y administrar
6. Preferencias de impresión

Dependiendo de la impresora (en mi caso una Zebra) ahí puedes modificar los parametros del papel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]